# Facebook uploading captions for video via Graph API not working

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, httprequest

I am trying to add captions (.srt file) to my video via the graph api but I am getting the following response from Facebook

```
{"error"=>{"message"=>"(#385) The captions file you selected is in a format that we don't support.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>385, "error_user_msg"=>"The captions file you selected is in a format that we don't support.", "fbtrace_id"=>"HIxy-mhlpHo"}}
```

Below is the code I used to upload the captions in ruby

```
subtitle_stream = open(subtitle_url)
subtitle_file = File.open('subtitle.en_US.srt', 'w+b') do |file|
      subtitle_stream.respond_to?(:read) ? IO.copy_stream(subtitle_stream, file) : file.write(subtitle_stream)
      open(file)
  end
subtitle_file_obj = UploadIO.new(
              subtitle_file,
              'application/octet-stream',
              'subtitle.en_US.srt'
            )
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/3344xxxxx/captions"
uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  upload_request = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new uri.request_uri, {
              'access_token' => access_token,
              'captions_file'   => subtitle_file_obj,
            }
  upload_response = http.request(upload_request)
```

I have used a sample srt file from the following link for testing

```
https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Video-Subtitle-SRT-0.01/t/sample.srt
```

Comment: Not sure if using arbitrary sample files to test this is a good idea; maybe it was rejected because the time stamps in the file are greater than the actual length of the video, or something like that. Test this with a subtitle file that “belongs” to the video.